# performance issue in machine learning model running in spark running in google colab

Tags: pyspark

was doing string indexing of 18,000 columns representing genes using string indexer and pipeline in pyspark.  However the spark ui shows an input and shuffle read progressively increasing in gb an mib respectively.  I asked for 10 excutor.cores and 10 executor.instances, however the spark ui executor page shows only 40 cores available. I am using a google colab pro subscription.  Any way out to improve the performance of this code below. It is taking too long and errors saying unresolved column for column with decimal point in name . I added backticks to avoid this, but still it says the same. Can you help me with this error and the poor performance issue (cores, shuffle read, input)
CODE

```
`from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
stages = []

# Apply StringIndexer to each gene column
for column in df45.columns:
    indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=f"{column}_index")
    stages.append(indexer)

# Create a pipeline and apply it to the DataFrame
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
indexed_df = pipeline.fit(df45).transform(df45)
indexed_df.show()


ERROR


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-8f2d04a9470d> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 # Create a pipeline and apply it to the DataFrame
      9 pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
---> 10 indexed_df = pipeline.fit(df45).transform(df45)
     11 indexed_df.show()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    203                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    204             else:
--> 205                 return self._fit(dataset)
    206         else:
    207             raise TypeError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    132                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    133                 else:  # must be an Estimator
--> 134                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
    135                     transformers.append(model)
    136                     if i < indexOfLastEstimator:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    203                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    204             else:
--> 205                 return self._fit(dataset)
    206         else:
    207             raise TypeError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    379 
    380     def _fit(self, dataset: DataFrame) -> JM:
--> 381         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    382         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    383         return self._copyValues(model)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    376 
    377         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 378         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    379 
    380     def _fit(self, dataset: DataFrame) -> JM:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1320 
   1321         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322         return_value = get_return_value(
   1323             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    183                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    184                 # JVM exception message.
--> 185                 raise converted from None
    186             else:
    187                 raise

AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `AC000068.1` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`cell_type`, `sm_name`, `A1BG`, `A1BG-AS1`, `A2M`, `A2M-AS1`, `A2MP1`, `A4GALT`, `AAAS`, `AACS`, `AAGAB`, `AAK1`, `AAMDC`, `AAMP`, `AAR2`, `AARS`, `AARS2`, `AARSD1`, `AASDH`, `AASDHPPT`, `AASS`, `AATBC`, `AATF`, `AATK`, `ABALON`, `ABAT`, `ABCA1`, `ABCA10`, `ABCA11P`, `ABCA2`, `ABCA3`, `ABCA5`, `ABCA6`, `ABCA7`, `ABCA9`, `ABCB1`, `ABCB10`, `ABCB11`, `ABCB4`, `ABCB7`, `ABCB8`, `ABCB9`, `ABCC1`, `ABCC10`, `ABCC2`, `ABCC3`, `ABCC4`, `ABCC5`, `ABCD1`, `ABCD2`, `ABCD3`, `ABCD4`, `ABCE1`, `ABCF1`, `ABCF2`, `ABCF3`, `ABCG1`, `ABCG2`, `ABCG8`, `ABHD1`, `ABHD10`, `ABHD11`, `ABHD12`, `ABHD13`, `ABHD14A`, `ABHD14A-ACY1`, `ABHD14B`, `ABHD15`, `ABHD15-AS1`, `ABHD16A`, `ABHD17A`, `ABHD17B`, `ABHD17C`, `ABHD18`, `ABHD2`, `ABHD3`, `ABHD4`, `ABHD5`, `ABHD6`, `ABHD8`, `ABI1`, `ABI2`, `ABI3`, `ABL1`, `ABL2`, `ABLIM1`, `ABLIM2`, `ABO`, `ABR`, `ABRACL`, `ABRAXAS1`, `ABRAXAS2`, `ABT1`, `ABTB1`, `ABTB2`, `AC000068.1`, `AC000123.2`, `AC000123.3`, `AC000403.1`, `AC001226.2`, `AC002044.1`, `AC002044.2`, `AC002075.2`, `AC002091.2`, `AC002094.4`, `AC002116.2`, `AC002128.1`, `AC002306.1`, `AC002310.1`, `AC002310.2`, `AC002350.1`, `AC002451.1`, `AC002467.1`, `AC002470.1`, `AC002525.1`, `AC002543.1`, `AC002553.1`, `AC002553.2`, `AC002558.1`, `AC002558.3`, `AC003005.2`, `AC003102.1`, `AC003681.1`, `AC003973.3`, `AC003991.1`, `AC0040...

`
```

for the name with decimal point i tried to add backticks, but still it says the same

for the perfromance issue, i tried for 10 executor instances and 10 cores per executor, but still spark ui executor says only 40 cores.  Should i manipulate maxpartitionbytes per core, that is at default